# javascript return of recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

Hate to open a new question for an extension to the previous one:

```
function ctest() {
    this.iteration = 0;
    this.func1 = function() {
        var result = func2.call(this, "haha");
        alert(this.iteration + ":" + result);
    }
    var func2 = function(sWord) {
        this.iteration++;
        sWord = sWord + "lol";
        if ( this.iteration < 5 ) {
            func2.call(this, sWord);
        } else {
            return sWord;
        }
    }
}
```

this returns iteration = 5 but result UNDEFINED ? how is that possible ? i explicitly return sWord. It should have returned "hahalollollollollol" and just for doublecheck, if i alert(sWord) just before the return sWord it displays it correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737970/recursive-function-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to return all the way up the stack:

```
func2.call(this, sWord);
```

should be:

```
return func2.call(this, sWord);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to return the result of the recursion, or else the method implicitly returns `undefined`. Try the following:

```
function ctest() {
this.iteration = 0;
  this.func1 = function() {
    var result = func2.call(this, "haha");
    alert(this.iteration + ":" + result);
  }
  var func2 = function(sWord) {
    this.iteration++;
    sWord = sWord + "lol";
    if ( this.iteration < 5 ) {
        return func2.call(this, sWord);
    } else {
        return sWord;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer function doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

Comment: The outer function is supposed to be a class constructor. It doesn't need to return anything. OP is clearly calling `func1`.

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple :)

[your code modified in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shareefhiasat/1qocqkfx/)

```
iteration = 0;
func1();

    function  func1() {
        var result = func2("haha");
        alert(iteration + ":" + result);
    }

    function func2 (sWord) {
        iteration++;

        sWord = sWord + "lol";
        if ( iteration < 5 ) {
            func2( sWord);
        } else {

            return sWord;
        }

    return sWord;
    }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure `ctest` is supposed to be a class constructor. And you still didn't fix the actual problem.