# Recursive function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

I have a function which calculates taxes.

```
function taxes(tax, taxWage) 
{
    var minWage = firstTier; //defined as a global variable
    if (taxWage > minWage) 
    {
        //calculates tax recursively calling two other functions difference() and taxStep() 
        tax = tax + difference(taxWage) * taxStep(taxWage);
        var newSalary = taxWage - difference(taxWage);
        taxes(tax, newSalary); 
    }
    else 
    {
        returnTax = tax + taxWage * taxStep(taxWage);
        return returnTax;
    }
}
```

I can't see why it doesn't stop the recursion.

Comment: What is your question?  And, what does this code have to do with the title of your question?

Comment: You say it recurses but there's no code that recurses here.

Comment: @raam86 But it's quite probably that that code is at fault...

Comment: @raam86  Yep, just as suspected.

Comment: @raam86 I did the same mistake to my code ffs. After I found your question I realised what was going on with my code and that I was looking the bug in the wrong place. I've upvoted you for that reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple function returning 'undefined' value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178455/simple-function-returning-undefined-value)

Comment: Example visualization: imagine you were writing a recursive factorial function and did this: `const fact = (num) => { if(num === 1){ return 1; } else { fact(num - 1); } }; console.log(fact(2));`, then this is what happens in the code: `num === 1` → `2 === 1` → `false`; execute the `else` part: `fact(num - 1);` → `fact(2 - 1);` → `fact(1);`. Now, `num === 1` → `1 === 1` → `true`. Execute the `if` part: `return 1;`. In the original `else` part: `fact(1);` → `1;`. The statement `1;` does nothing. Nothing was returned yet! Return `undefined`. `console.log(fact(2));` → `console.log(undefined);`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In this arm of your function:

```
if (taxWage > minWage) {
    // calculates tax recursively calling two other functions difference() and taxStep() 
    tax = tax + difference(taxWage) * taxStep(taxWage);
    var newSalary = taxWage - difference(taxWage);
    taxes(tax, newSalary); 
}
```

you are not returning a value from the function or setting `returnTax`.  When you don't return anything, the return value is `undefined`.

Perhaps, you want this:

```
if (taxWage > minWage) {
    // calculates tax recursively calling two other functions difference() and taxStep() 
    tax = tax + difference(taxWage) * taxStep(taxWage);
    var newSalary = taxWage - difference(taxWage);
    return taxes(tax, newSalary); 
}
```

Answer (score 18):

There is a bug with your recursion:

```
taxes(tax, newSalary);
```

You don't return anything when the condition in the `if` evaluates to true.  You need to change that to:

```
return taxes(tax, newSalary);
```

You have the necessary `return` statement in the `else`.

Comment: This helped, but I'm interested in knowing why `return` is necessary for the recursion to operate correctly.

Comment: If you want your function to return a value, then you must return a value.  In javascript, a function without a `return` will return `undefined`.  Recursion itself doesn't require a return (eg: print out the nodes in a tree), but if you want the function to return something then it needs `return`.  You can explore this by stepping through the function in a debugger.

Comment: I think what confused me about it how it works in JavaScript was the fact that I expected that calling the function itself was enough to instantiate recursion. For instance; incrementing a number then calling the function and passing it back to itself. Either way, this was helpful, I was just curious.

Answer (score 1):

For example `taxes(tax, newSalary);` returns `100`;

```
taxes(tax, newSalary); // undefined
```

You expect to see `100` because you called `taxes(tax, newSalary)` recursively but in fact you got the value (`100`) and you need to return this value.

```
return taxes(tax, newSalary); // 100
// simply it's the same as
// return 100
// because taxes(tax, newSalary) returned 100
```

after `return 100` you will get this value.