# Return new object it built in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am practicing Javascript object function. Supposed I have `firstName` and `lastName` as two arguments of my function.I want to display like this `{"firstName":"tim","lastName":doe}` . Here is my code but it printed out undefined. Any idea? Thank you!

```
function myFunction(firstName, lastName) {
  this.name1 = firstName;
  this.name2 = lastName;
}
var obj = new myFunction();

console.log(myFunction('tim', 'doe'));
```

Comment: you should log `obj` which is the instance of your object

Comment: FYI, if you run this code in `strict` mode, it will throw an exception.  Because you didn't call `myFunction()` using the `new` operator, in strict mode, `this` will be set to `undefined` and `this.name1 = firstName;` will throw an exception.  Non-strict mode doesn't throw an error because `this` will point to the `window` object, but it does not do what you want it to do - thus why we have `strict` mode in the first place to keep you from writing and executing bad/wrong code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
console.log(new myFunction('tim', 'doe'));
```

Or this:

```
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Also note that in `obj`, first name and last name will be `null`, as no parameters were passed in that constructor call.

Comment: why do I get myFunction (instance), which i don't expect it. Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
function myFunction(firstName, lastName) {
  this.name1 = firstName;
  this.name2 = lastName;
}
var obj = new myFunction('tim', 'doe');

console.log(obj);
```

You can see this documentation [JavaScript Constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

Comment: why do I get myFunction (instance), which i don't expect it. Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Your function is a mold of the a new object, but you will get instance of the constructor. 

`myFunction -> mold
obj -> instance`

So you can manages is the object, but not the mold this is just a definition

Answer (score 2):

This kind of function called constructor, and you shouldn't call it directly. You have to use it with `new`.

```
console.log(new myFunction('tim', 'doe'));
```

This will print the result as you expect.

To distinguish the constructors from normal functions, it's better to name it begin with capital letter, like this:

```
function MyFunction(...) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

the undefined you receive is from the function not having a return value, see this post regarding that:[Simple function returning 'undefined' value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178455/simple-function-returning-undefined-value)

to get the result you want...

```
function myFunction(firstName, lastName) {
    this.name1 = firstName;
    this.name2 = lastName;
}
var obj = new myFunction('tim', 'doe');

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's explore what this line does: `console.log(myFunction('tim', 'doe'));`

This part: `myFunction('tim', 'doe')` executes myFunction as a function. Since myFunction does not have a return operator, it's return value is 'undefined' which is javascript's way of saying it doesn't exist. Thus, the word 'undefined' is printed on the console.

Additional tips:
Try adding this line: `console.log(typeof myFunction);`

This should print 'function'.
(May the 'typeof' operator become your best friend)

Try adding a return line as the last line of myFunctions such as:

```
return 'First name: ' + firstName + " Last name: " + lastName;
```

However, at this point the 'var obj = new myFunction();' line is unused.

Try adding another line:
    `console.log(typeof obj);`

This should print 'object' which means that 'obj' is just that - an object.

Here is a complete example you can play with:

```
function myFunction(firstName, lastName) {
  this.name1 = firstName;
  this.name2 = lastName;
  this.getNames = function() {
      return 'First name: ' + firstName + " Last name: " + lastName;
  }
  console.log("This executes once upon instatiation (the line with var obj = new ...)");
  return "Return value";
}

var obj = new myFunction('tim', 'doe');

console.log(typeof myFunction);
console.log(typeof obj);
console.log(obj.getNames());
```

Let me know if any of the above needs clarification. Good luck ...

BTW, this is what the output should look like on the console:

```
This executes once upon instatiation (the line with var obj = new ...)
script.js:14 function
script.js:15 object
script.js:16 First name: tim Last name: doe
```

Comment: i like your line of thought, but typeof is not a function but an assertion so it is called console.log(typeof varname); not console.log(typeof(varname));

Comment: Good point Traveling_Monk. Can you tell I dwell in C-dom most of the time? :)