# Code only works when not wrapped in a function

Tags: javascript

Really not sure what's going on here as am new to JavaScript, but actually cannot figure it out, even after reading other posts like this one: [Simple function returning 'undefined' value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178455/simple-function-returning-undefined-value). For some reason, when my code is placed inside a function, it returns 'undefined' instead of true or false.

If I use the code without a function and define var `a` on the first line, it works OK:

```
var a = "wjebh ghbui ayub";
var b = (a.split(' ').join('')).split('a'); // creates array

var trueOrFalse = b.map(function(c, i){ // puts into array true/false for each index
    if (c[2] == 'b') {
        console.log('value: ' + c[2] + ' is b; true');
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('false');
        return false;
    }
});

var answer = function(el) {
    // checks whether any element is true
    return el === true;
};
trueOrFalse.some(answer); // return true/false
```

But the moment I add it inside a function, it doesn't work.

```
function bThreeAfterA(a) {
    var b = (a.split(' ').join('')).split('a'); // creates array

    var trueOrFalse = b.map(function(c, i){ // puts into array true/false for each index
        if (c[2] == 'b') {
            console.log('value: ' + c[2] + ' is b; true');
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('false');
            return false;
        }
    });

    var answer = function(el) {
 // checks whether any element is true
        return el === true;     
    };

    trueOrFalse.some(answer); // return true/false
}
```

Even if it's put in an IIFE it doesn't work properly:

```
(function(){
    var a = "wjebh ghbui ayub";
    var b = (a.split(' ').join('')).split('a'); // creates array

    var trueOrFalse = b.map(function(c, i){ // puts into array true/false for each index
        if (c[2] == 'b') {
            console.log('value: ' + c[2] + ' is b; true');
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('false');
            return false;
        }
    });

    var answer = function(el) {
        // checks whether any element is true
        return el === true;
    };
    trueOrFalse.some(answer); // return true/false
})();
```

I feel I'm doing something very daft here that most will easily spot. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here? Presumably this is some sort of beginner syntax error. Links to any reading resources would be helpful too.

Comment: Where are you placing this js?

Comment: Your function doesn't `return` anything...

Comment: Define _"doesn't work"_? What's happening? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: [When someone asks a question about a problem with their code, we need to know what is wrong with it. Stating that “it doesn’t work” is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: I really don't know what you are trying to do, but is your problem not a missing `return` before `trueOrFalse.some(answer)`? If you want to retrieve a value after call a function, you have to `return` the desired value

Comment: turns out I thought it did return something, but the actual function it called only returned something, so I should have returned the function that returned something

Comment: 'it doesnt work' as in it should 'return' something - sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've all been there.

Give this a run.

```
function bThreeAfterA(a) {
    var b = (a.split(' ').join('')).split('a'); // creates array

    var trueOrFalse = b.map(function(c, i){ // puts into array true/false for each index
        if (c[2] == 'b') {
            console.log('value: ' + c[2] + ' is b; true');
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('false');
            return false;
        }
    });

    var answer = function(el) {
 // checks whether any element is true
        return el === true;     
    };

    return trueOrFalse.some(answer); //ACTUALLY return true/false
}

console.log("Answer: " + bThreeAfterA("wjebh ghbui ayub")); // Returns true.
```

When you're operating on variables outside of the block scope, they persist.  When they're inside, they vanish.

Hence, it "worked" but it didn't "work" when you have it in a function.