# Function returns undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This is related to the HackerRank algorithm problem '[Kangaroo](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kangaroo)'.

Here is my code:

```js
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
      // Complete this function
      if(x2>x1 && v2>v1)return "NO";
      if(x1>x2 && v1>v2)return "NO";
        if(x1 == x2){
            return "YES";
        }else{  
       kangaroo(x1+v1,v1,x2+v2,v2);
     }
  }  

var result = kangaroo(0,3,4,2);
console.log(result);
```

This is the problem:

> There are two kangaroos on a number line ready to jump in the positive direction (i.e, toward positive infinity). The first kangaroo starts at location  and moves at a rate of  meters per jump. The second kangaroo starts at location  and moves at a rate of  meters per jump. Given the starting locations and movement rates for each kangaroo, can you determine if they'll ever land at the same location at the same time?

x1 is the starting point of kangaroo 1.

v1-is the speed of kangaroo 1.

x2 is the starting point of kangaroo 2.

v2 is the speed of kangaroo 2.

My code returns `undefined`, why?

Comment: `return kangaroo(x1+v1,v1,x2+v2,v2)` You're not returning the result of the recursive call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737970/recursive-function-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Please learn about the [recursion](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html) first :D

The recursive call need to calls itself that mean you need to return `kangaroo`

```
return kangaroo(x1+v1,v1,x2+v2,v2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may looks equal:

```
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
  if(x2>x1 && v2>v1)return "NO";
  if(x1>x2 && v1>v2)return "NO";
  if(x1 == x2) return "YES";
  return kangaroo(x1+v1,v1,x2+v2,v2);
 }
```

But actually it may gets tail call optimized, so it runs much much faster, as it is executed like this:

```
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
 while(true){
  if(x2>x1 && v2>v1)return "NO";
  if(x1>x2 && v1>v2)return "NO";
  if(x1 == x2) return "YES";
   x1=x1+v1,x2=x2+v2;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

this is my answer with java.

```
public static String kangaroo(int x1, int v1, int x2, int v2) {
// Write your code here

while(true)
{   x1+=v1;
    x2+=v2;
    
    if(x2>x1 && v2>=v1)return "NO";
    if(x1>x2 && v1>=v2)return "NO";

    if(x1==x2)
    return "YES";
  
  
}


}
```