# Factorial recursion, giving undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simply find recursion factorial

```
 function factorial(num, result) {
  console.log('num', num)
  if (num === 0) {
    console.log('res ', result);
    return result;
  } else {
    result = result * num;
    console.log(result)
    factorial(--num, result);
  }
}

let res = factorial(3, 1)
console.log(res)
```

It is giving **undefined**, not sure why, need some help.

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fcmz1Vj5cWf3FPKaGPSf?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737970/recursive-function-returns-undefined)

Comment: `*return* factorial(--num, result);`

Comment: Thanks a lot @haim770,  how foolish on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Bside the missing `return` statement, some annotations:

- Use a default value for the result. This enables to call the function without given a starting value and allows touse only a single parameter.
- Take only one early exit of the recursive call, without using `else` in combination with `return`. The `return` statement omits the following `else` statement. Just go on with the code without an `else` part.
- Return at the end of the function a recursive call to allow to use the compiler to take a TCO (tail call optimization). This wotks without extending the stack, because the last call is replace with the actual recursive call. This optimization may not actually implemented.
- Do not use decrement operators, if you need only the reduced value without using the reduced value again.
- Move the calculation into the function call.

```js
function factorial(num, result = 1) {
    console.log('num', num);
    if (num === 0) return result;
    return factorial(num - 1, result * num);
}

console.log(factorial(3))
```