# promise.resolve() in for loop return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I've tried to get a tree node after search process. But it always return undefined.. 
here's the code.

```js
const findOrder = (list, key) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      // find node through key in tree
      if (list[i].key === key) {
        console.log(`================I got it!: `, list[i].children); // children[]
        resolve(list[i].children);
      }
      if (list[i].children) {
        findOrder(list[i].children, key);
      }
    }
  });

const setOrder = async() => {
  const orders = await findOrder(
    treeData,
    dropObj.classKind === "1" ? keyGen(dropObj.key) : dropObj.key
  );
  console.log(`==================siblings: `, orders); // undefined
};
setOrder();
```

what is the problem?

Comment: @AKX wait, you're right. I thought there was a `{` in the beginning. My bad.

Comment: @VLAZ, findOrder returns the Promise. Its just using implicit return: https://medium.com/@bunlong/arrow-functions-return-rules-in-javascript-b63ed5f25994

Comment: Ah, but I was *half right* (let's call it that, rather than "mostly wrong"...)  when going through the  `if (list[i].children) { findOrder(list[i].children, key); }` it **does not** return anything, nor would it resolve the Promise in the parent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737970/recursive-function-returns-undefined)

Comment: I think it's little different answer.. findOrder always return promise though, but I'm just confused why the promise never resolve

Comment: Why are you using promises at all? There's nothing asynchronous in your `findOrder` code.

Comment: @Bergi I think console.log(orders) doesn't wait findOrder have finished it's loop.. because findOrder definitely find something, but actually orders is undefined. so I thought I needed promise or callback

Comment: try resolve(findOrder(list[i].children, key));

Comment: @bucky2 No, the only problem was that you were missing a `return` keyword. You should not use promises here.

Comment: @Bergi is correct - the promises just confuse you more than they actually help. Well, they *don't* help - you finish everything synchronously, so the promises abstraction is worthless. In the end, simply don't return the result of the recursive call, it's not a problem of "not waiting enough", nor is the resolution at some other point in time that you cannot determine within this call chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not resolve it here,

```js
      // ...
      if (list[i].children) {
        findOrder(list[i].children, key);
      }
      // ...
```

To let the outer Promise know when to resolve it, you should explicitly do it:

```js
      // ...
      if (list[i].children) {
        findOrder(list[i].children, key).then(result => {
          // as resolve can only be called once,
          // do not call it if it doesn't found anything
          if (result) resolve(result)
        });
      }
      // ...
```

This should work. However, this implementation has too many useless calls to 'resolve'. It's better to find the matched item directly and resolve it.

Here is an example:

```js
const findOrder = function (list, key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(find(list, key))

    function find (_list, key) {
      for (let i = 0; i < _list.length; i++) {
        if (_list[i].key === key) return _list[i].children
        if (_list[i].children) {
          const c = find(_list[i].children, key)  
          if (c) return c
        }
      }
      return undefined
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I need to try your better option. very helpful. thanks!