# Two sum algorithm: my solution returns undefined but prints the expected output

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help before I go **crazy** because this does NOT make sense to me. So I would really appreciate it if someone can get me out of this hole.

This is the problem:
*Given an array of integers `nums` and an integer `target`, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target. You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice. You can return the answer in any order.*

This is my code:

```js
let numsCopy = [];
// new array to push the numbers index
let arrayResult = []
let currentNumberIndex = 0
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    console.log('inside arrow function',nums, target);
    // Copy the array
    numsCopy = nums.slice(0)
    // return fHelper(nums, target)
    // let test = () => fHelper(nums, target)
    console.log(fHelper(nums, target));
};

function fHelper(nums, target){
  console.log('inside fhelper',nums, target);
    // exit condition
    if (nums.length < 1) return

    // grab the first element and mutate our nums
    let currentNumber = nums.shift()
    for (var i = 1; i < numsCopy.length; i++) {
        // check if the current number plus number in the next position of the array
        // equals the target we are going to push the index of these numbers to the
        // arrayResult
        console.log('i: ', i, ' == ', 'numsCopy.length:', numsCopy.length);
        console.log('nums length is: ', nums.length);
        console.log(`${currentNumber} + ${numsCopy[i]} equals target ${target}?`)

        if (currentNumber + numsCopy[i] === target) {
          console.log('yes');
          arrayResult.push(currentNumberIndex)
          arrayResult.push(i)
          console.log(arrayResult, 'typeof', typeof arrayResult, 'is array? ',Array.isArray(arrayResult));
          return arrayResult
        }
        console.log('no');
    }
    console.log('currentNumberIndex: ', currentNumberIndex);
    currentNumberIndex++
    // recursion. we call again the function
    //array nums get shorter every time with the shift()
    fHelper(nums, target)
}

// Hello after hours of reading and trying to figured out and understand why my solution in some cases is returning undefined.
// This is my code and I dont understand why is returning undefined


// case 1
// twoSum([2,7,11,15], 9) // Expected output = [0,1]
// case 2
twoSum([3,2,4], 6) // in this case return undefined. Expected output= [1,2]
// case 3
// twoSum([3,3], 6) // Expected output= [0,1]
// case 4
// twoSum([3,3,2,8], 10) // in this case returns undefined. Expected output= [2,3]
// case 5
// twoSum([3,2,3], 6) // Expected output= [0,2]
```

Comment: two sum function has no return value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737970/recursive-function-returns-undefined)

Comment: you need `return fHelper(nums, target)` at the end of the function

Comment: your function doesn't return a value. you need to add the `return` keyword before **fHelper** calls.

Comment: Thanks @Nick! The answer to that post actually help me out to understand why I was getting undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `return` statement at the end of the function.

```
function fHelper(nums, target) {
    // ...
    return fHelper(nums, target); // <<<<<<<<<
}
```

```js
let numsCopy = [];
// new array to push the numbers index
let arrayResult = []
let currentNumberIndex = 0
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    console.log('inside arrow function',nums, target);
    // Copy the array
    numsCopy = nums.slice(0)
    // return fHelper(nums, target)
    // let test = () => fHelper(nums, target)
    console.log(fHelper(nums, target));
};

function fHelper(nums, target){
  console.log('inside fhelper',nums, target);
    // exit condition
    if (nums.length < 1) return

    // grab the first element and mutate our nums
    let currentNumber = nums.shift()
    for (var i = 1; i < numsCopy.length; i++) {
        // check if the current number plus number in the next position of the array
        // equals the target we are going to push the index of these numbers to the
        // arrayResult
        console.log('i: ', i, ' == ', 'numsCopy.length:', numsCopy.length);
        console.log('nums length is: ', nums.length);
        console.log(`${currentNumber} + ${numsCopy[i]} equals target ${target}?`)

        if (currentNumber + numsCopy[i] === target) {
          console.log('yes');
          arrayResult.push(currentNumberIndex)
          arrayResult.push(i)
          console.log(arrayResult, 'typeof', typeof arrayResult, 'is array? ',Array.isArray(arrayResult));
          return arrayResult
        }
        console.log('no');
    }
    console.log('currentNumberIndex: ', currentNumberIndex);
    currentNumberIndex++
    // recursion. we call again the function
    //array nums get shorter every time with the shift()
    return fHelper(nums, target)
}

// Hello after hours of reading and trying to figured out and understand why my solution in some cases is returning undefined.
// This is my code and I dont understand why is returning undefined


// case 1
// twoSum([2,7,11,15], 9) // Expected output = [0,1]
// case 2
twoSum([3,2,4], 6) // in this case return undefined. Expected output= [1,2]
// case 3
// twoSum([3,3], 6) // Expected output= [0,1]
// case 4
// twoSum([3,3,2,8], 10) // in this case returns undefined. Expected output= [2,3]
// case 5
// twoSum([3,2,3], 6) // Expected output= [0,2]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```