# How to return value from function which is called multiple times by itself?

Tags: javascript

There is some nested object data and I have to go through this several level deep until I find my result.
So I use the `findByKey` function, which is calling itself as often as it is needed.
Then it should return `object.source`, but I get `undefined` instead.

```
async function getData(lib, level) {
  // First get data from file
  const depsBuffer = await readFile(resolve('file.json'))
  const deps = JSON.parse(depsBuffer.toString('utf-8'))

  // Process data
  const result = findByKey(deps.dependencies, deps.dependencies)
  console.log(result) // returns undefined :-(
}

function findByKey(data, deps) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty('target') && data.target === 'param') {
    return data
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
    const element = data[Object.keys(data)[i]]
    if (typeof element === 'object') {
      let obj = findByKey(element, deps)
      if (obj != null) {
        if (RegExp(/.*/).test(obj.source)) return obj.source // <- Return this to `getData`
        // else if (!obj?.source?.startsWith('npm:')) findByKey(deps, deps)
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737970/recursive-function-returns-undefined)

Comment: @jonrsharpe not really in my case (maybe I'm missunderstanding something), as I don't see the the missing return...

Comment: The result of one of the two recursive calls is entirely ignored. I'd suggest stepping through a debugger with a concrete example, and if you still can't find the answer give a [mre] (what's in file.json? What does "the rec. starts here again" mean?)

Comment: @jonrsharpe even removing the `else if` part doesn't return a value...

Comment: There's still a path without an explicit return, though: what if the loop ends without the condition ever being true? What should happen then - default return value, explicit error, ...? Again stepping through would help you see the problem, use e.g. http://pythontutor.com/javascript.html.

Answer (score 0):

I belive your issue is that

```
else if (!obj?.source?.startsWith('npm:')) findByKey(deps, deps)
```

should be

```
else if (!obj?.source?.startsWith('npm:')) return findByKey(deps, deps)
```

You are running it recursively, but you are not propagating the return value upward.