# The console.log is printing but the return doesnt go through any idea ? javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

My function looks something like this:
the console.log is printing which means that the if statement has been entered but the return is undefined

```
 var isPalindrome = function(s) {
       s = s.replace(/[^A-Z]+/ig, "").toLowerCase();
       if(s[0] !== s[s.length-1]) { console.log("entered false");return false;}
        else if (s.length < 2 ){ console.log("entered true");return true;}
        else {
        s = s.substring(1,s.length-1)
        isPalindrome(s)
            }
    };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737970/recursive-function-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

After long time trying, I realized I was missing a return in front of my recursive call

Comment: :) :) Was you not returning final result in `s`

Comment: Return isPalindrome(s) at the then end the Return was missing