# Recursive function getting called repeatedly despite conditional logic

Tags: javascript

*I'm new with Javascript so it's a little difficult to me to explain this properly.*

I have this recursive function:

```
function askQuestion(question){
    let answer = prompt(question);
    if(answer === ""){
        alert("The answer is empty...");
        askQuestion(question);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

So, **the problem**: if the user response was empty and the function is called again, when the user indicates a non empty response the value of "answer" remains empty. I notice that the call stack of chrome is calling again the function even when the answer is empty. I can't understand why this is happening, but I suspect the problem is there. I tried to "reset" the value of answer to null, but then the value of answer stays as null.

[screenshot of the chrome inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA5yZ.png)

Also, I'm not totally sure that this kind of functions are called recursive function...

Comment: Yes, you `return answer` (which is the original, empty string); you don’t `return askQuestion(question)` (the result of the new call). See [Recursive function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12737970/4642212).

Comment: You don't really have to use recursion for this. A loop is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should return the function result

```
const askQuestion = question => {
  let answer = prompt(question);
  if(answer === '') {
    alert("The answer is empty...");
    return askQuestion(question);
  }
  return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop instead, checking while the answer is empty to call the `prompt(question)`

```
while(answer === ""){
  answer =  prompt(question);
}
return answer;
```

Comment: This would reopen a prompt when the iser simply closes it. Maybe `while(answer === '')` would be better.

Comment: yes I agree. Going to update it now