# recursive function always returns undefined for base case

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

My code is below, this is a recursive function that always returns undefined for the base case. I thought perhaps it was a scope issue but assigning a 'result' var to function scope did not help.
Please help.

```js
function calcDays(parcels, days) {
  let result = days;
  console.log(days);
  if (parcels.length === 0) return result

  days++;
  let min = parcels[0];
  parcels.forEach((num) => {
    if (num < min) min = num;
  })
  for (let i = 0; i < parcels.length; i++) {
    parcels[i] = parcels[i] - min;
    if (parcels[i] <= 0) {
      parcels.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  calcDays(parcels, days)
}

function getMinimumDays(parcels) {
  console.log(parcels.length)
  let days = 0;
  return calcDays(parcels, days);
}

let parcels = [2, 2, 3, 4, 2]
console.log(getMinimumDays(parcels));
```

Comment: I solved it. I wasn't returning the recursive call to itself,although I don't understand why you need to as it solves the problem and calls itself until base case is reached but returned undefined even thought the variable is holding a value ; something to do with how the stack handles functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737970/recursive-function-returns-undefined)

Comment: I think it's unlikely that `getMinimumDays` fully works as you wish. One significant thing that's seems to be misunderstood is the apparent hope of having a side-effect on the `days` parameter, which looks like an integer. Can you edit to describe the meaning of the calculation?  What are you trying to compute from the parcels array?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Some recursive principles to keep in mind: scope, nesting, and stepping in and out.

```
console.log(
  calcDays(
    [2, 2, 3, 4, 2], 
    0
  )
);

function calcDays(parcels, days) {
  console.log('variable days =', days);
  if (parcels.length === 0) { return days; }

  days++;
  let min = parcels[0];
  parcels.forEach((num) => {
    if (num < min) min = num;
  })
  for (let i = 0; i < parcels.length; i++) {
    parcels[i] = parcels[i] - min;
    if (parcels[i] <= 0) {
      parcels.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  calcDays(parcels, days)
}
```

**Scope:** (execution context)

Having the parameters provided, `calcDays()` executes 4 times. `console.log('variable days =', days);`, at the top of the function block, writes to the console:

```
> variable days = 0
> variable days = 1
> variable days = 2
> variable days = 3
```

It appears all 4 of the `days` variables are the same variable. They're not. There are 4 different `days` variables here, each within it's own scope.

With each recursion, a recursive function creates its own scope. And that scope is nested inside the execution of the recursive function that called the current recursion. It operates as you had 4 self-executing functions nested one within the other:

```
(function (param) {
  // scope 1
  (function (param) {
    // scope 2
    (function (param) {
      // scope 3
      (function (param) {
        // scope 4
      }(param));
    }(param));
  }(param));
}(param));
```

`param` is a different variable within each scope. Scope 1 `param` is passed to the the second execution by way of function arguments and its value is assigned to Scope 2 `param`. The process continues all the way to the bottom of the "nest". That explains why it appears `param`—or `days`—is the same variable, but is not.

**Stepping back up**: (`return`)

As shown above, variable values are passed down the "nest" using function parameters. The `caller` (parent) execution of the recursive function provides its variable values to the `callee` (nested/child) execution by passing the parent variable values to the child execution through the function arguments. `return` is not necessary to carry variable values down into the "nest".

But, every **step down** into a "nest" must be **stepped back up** for each and every execution of the recursive function to finally complete. Every step out of the "nest" leaves behind the scope of the nest it is stepping out of.

When a nested execution context is stepped out of, its scope becomes inaccessible. Changes made to variables in Scope 3 are not available to Scope 2, and variables in Scope 2 are not available to Scope 1.

One way to "carry" variable values back out of the "nest", and make the values available in the parent function scope, is to `return` those variables from the child function scope.

As stated earlier, the recursive function example executes 4 times, however the statement `return days;` in the conditional block `if (parcels.length === 0) { return days; }` only executes once. And it only executes in the innermost nested execution, the fourth scope in this case. Therefore ONLY the third scope has access to the Scope 4 `days` variable value. Scope 3 completes execution, but has not returned any variable values to Scope 2, so the variable value `return`'ed from Scope 4 is no longer available. Scope 2 returns nothing to Scope 1, and Scope 1 returns nothing to the initial execution of the recursive function. Javascript returns `undefined` when a function does not return a value.

```js
console.log(
  calcDays(
    [2, 2, 3, 4, 2], 
    0
  )
);

function calcDays(parcels, days) {
  console.log('variable days =', days);
  if (parcels.length === 0) { return days; }

  days++;
  let min = parcels[0];
  parcels.forEach((num) => {
    if (num < min) min = num;
  })
  for (let i = 0; i < parcels.length; i++) {
    parcels[i] = parcels[i] - min;
    if (parcels[i] <= 0) {
      parcels.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  calcDays(parcels, days)
}
```

That's why it appears the "base case", `if (parcels.length === 0) return result`, is returning `undefined` to the initial execution, `return calcDays(parcels, days);`, occurring in the `getMinimumDays()` function block.

In fact, the "base case" is returning the desired value, but it's not carried all the way back out the nested recursions.

---

Not recommended in this case, but to illustrate the principles, using a global variable could also provide the final calculation.

```js
let global_days;
calcDays([2, 2, 3, 4, 2], 0);
console.log(global_days);

function calcDays(parcels, days) {
  while ( 0 < parcels.length ) {
    days++;
    let min = parcels[0];
    parcels.forEach((num) => {
      if (num < min) min = num;
    })
    for (let i = 0; i < parcels.length; i++) {
      parcels[i] = parcels[i] - min;
      if (parcels[i] <= 0) {
        parcels.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }
    global_days = days;
    calcDays(parcels, days);
  }
}
```