# Recursive Function not returning value as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

In this function i am trying to calculate the number of ways, a number can be decoded. 1 ought to be decoded as a, 3 as c, 26 as z .
The function calculates the right count, but does only return undefined.
I think it should cancel the recursive calls at the right time, and I reach the "escape"-block, but the number is not returned as it should.
Can anyone point me towards the reason, why this is happening?

```js
function numWaysDecodable(msg) {
    msg = msg.toString().split("");

    function helper(msg, past = 99, count = 1) {
        if (msg.length === 0) {
            console.log("wtf count is:"+count);
            return count;
        }
        let head = msg.shift();
        if (head < 7 && past < 3) {
            count++
        } 
        //the below return statement was missing           
        return helper(msg, head, count);
    }
    return helper(msg);
}

console.log(numWaysDecodable(123));
```

The fixed code is still faulty, as the algorithm is flawed for other input.
For example for the input 1212 we return 4, even though we should recieve the result 5:

1. 12 1 2;
2. 1 2 12;
3. 12 12;
4. 1 2 1 2;
5. 1 21 2;

I think the code misses to count nr.3,12 12; I am unsure how to fix that as of yet. Some more thinking to do

Comment: You're missing a `return` at the recursive call.

Comment: @Barmar, the dupe is about c#, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719480/javascript-return-of-recursive-function) fits it better

Comment: @Luca I don't bother having a different dupe for every language, the problem and solution are the same for all of them.

Comment: True, I just saw a lot of confusion in beginners when linking questions of other languages. Granted, JS and C# are pretty close

Comment: sorry for the dupe, and thank you for linking a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return value in each call of the recursive function like:

```
return helper(msg, head, count);
```

```js
function numWaysDecodable(msg) {
    msg = msg.toString().split("");

    function helper(msg, past = 99, count = 1) {
        if (msg.length === 0) {
            console.log("wtf count is:"+count);
            return count;
        }
        let head = msg.shift();
        if (head < 7 && past < 3) {
            count++
        }            
        return helper(msg, head, count);
    }
    return helper(msg);
}

console.log(numWaysDecodable(123));
```