# Javascript function return False but should return True

Tags: javascript

I am checking for a condition and based on that returning true and false. The thing is my condition even satisfied. Below is my code

```
 $scope.getPostalcode = function(obj) {
     for ( var x in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[x] === 'object') {
           $scope.getPostalcode(obj[x]);
        } else if (x === 'postalCode') {
           if (obj.postalCode == $scope.postalCode) {
              return true;
              break;
           }
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
```

The value of `obj.postalCode` and `$scope.postalCode` is same. Also I have checked the type of both is string. I am also including my object in case I am making the mistake there.

```
[
  {
    "account": "10066",
    "pcn": "K770",
    "msn": "6631",
    "meterName": "DM",
    "address": {
      "companyName": "Test",
      "street": "10 Downing Street",
      "city": "LONDON",
      "country": "UK",
      "postalCode": "SW1A 2AA"
    }
  },
  {
    "account": "63350",
    "pcn": "K7",
    "msn": "663",
    "meterName": "DM5",
    "address": {
      "companyName": "DITIQUE",
      "street": "10 Downing Street",
      "city": "LONDON",
      "country": "UK",
      "postalCode": "SW1A 2AA"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: To better understand what is happening, you can use a debugger or try logging your values at each step of your function.

Comment: You are not using `return` inside `if (typeof obj[x] === 'object')`, so you recursively call the same function but you don't exit out the first call.

Comment: Not sure what you try to achive but i think you want to change `$scope.getPostalcode(obj[x]);` into `return $scope.getPostalcode(obj[x]);` inside your if statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript return of recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719480/javascript-return-of-recursive-function)

Comment: @VLAZ I think you are correc. It is because of recursion as I can see using the debugger.

Comment: @MarkBaijens that helped. Thanks a lot